# how to wrap a promise with bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird for promises, but also using a library that returns a non-bluebird promise. I want to use `.asCallback`. I tried to use `Promise.resolve` to wrap it, which I found somewhere else online, but it hides the errors in the promise chain.  In the code if I take out the `then/catch` it resolves rather than throwing an error from the client call, even though an error happened.

Besides creating a new promise with `new Promise(resolve,reject)`, which is an obvious solution, is there a better way to convert it to a bluebird promise, one that will propagate any errors to the original promise chain?

```
module.exports.count = function(params, done){
  var promise = client.count({
    "index": config.search.index + "_" + params.index
  }).then(function(response){
    logger.debug(response);
  }).catch(function(e){
    logger.error(e);
  });
  return Promise.resolve(promise).asCallback(done);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it hides the errors in the promise chain*"? `Promise.resolve` certainly doesn't do that. Your `catch()` call might however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` *does* propagate errors. Your problem seems to be that `catch` handles them before they could reach the `resolve`. You should be doing

```
function count(params, done){
  return Promise.resolve(client.count({
    "index": config.search.index + "_" + params.index
  })).then(function(response){
    logger.debug(response);
    return response; // important!
  }, function(e){
    logger.error(e);
    throw e; // important!
  }).asCallback(done);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's something else in the parent promise chain. I added the catch just to troubleshoot it so my code example is bad actually. Let me recheck.

Comment: I think it's just an error on my part in the parent chain handler. I'm still learning how to use promises properly...